# Cannot redeclare class YT_BasicMenu

Tags: product, error, magento-1

I am placing some new products inside a magento installation.
The site is not developed by me, but I have to fix this problem.

I inserted a new product, and in the frontend I have this error on the url of the product:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class YT_BasicMenu in
>   /home/yutucano/public_html/imac/app/design/frontend/default/sm_meline/template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml
>   on line 0

Some days ago i had the same problem but the problem disappeared, don't know how.